# AWS Serverless, CloudFormation : Error, Trying to populate non string value into a string for variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am using serverless framework for deploying my application on AWS Cloud.

```
https://serverless.com/
```

I want to use the value of AWS Account ID in my serverless.yml file and I want to export the acccount ID as the environment variable, so that it can be accessed from Lambda functions.

Based on the value of this lambda function, I want to create some resources ( like IAM roles, etc.), which refer to this accountId variable.

But when I try to deploy the stack, I get the below error,

> Trying to populate non string value into a string for variable
>   ${self:custom.accountId}. Please make sure the value of the property
>   is a string.

My Serverless.yml file is as below

```
custom:
  accountId : !Ref "AWS::AccountId"


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: dev

  region: us-east-1

  environment:
     ACCOUNT_ID : ${self:custom.accountId}       
     myRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::${self:custom.accountId}:role/xxxxxxxx
```

Is there any way to refer to the value of the Account Id in the serverless.yml file?

Comment: I'll write a proper answer when I get back to my computer, but Google the serverless plugin Pseudo Parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't reference AWS::AccountId in your serverless.yml, because it doesn't quite translate when creating the CloudFormation template.

The workaround is to use the serverless plugin [Pseudo Parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-pseudo-parameters).

You can install the plugin using npm.

```
npm install serverless-pseudo-parameters
```

You will also need to add the plugin to the serverless.yml file.

```
plugins:
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
```

Then you can reference your AccountId with #{AWS::AccountId}

```
functions:
  helloWorld:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get
    environment:
      ACCOUNT_ID : #{AWS::AccountId}
```

Note that the reference begins with a hash instead of a dollar sign.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this suggestion. I am using the value of Account ID in the lambda function as environment variable.  But I got below error -    The CloudFormation template is invalid: [/Resources/CfdemoapiLambdaFunction/Type/Environment/Variables/ACCOUNT_ID] 'null' values are not allowed in templates

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Because the issues are that the AWS::AccountId is set in CloudFormation you can't set it as a serverless variable. So environment needs to be set at the function level.

Comment: Thanks, I will set the environment variable at the function level